# How Can I hide global search in vf page.

Tags: visualforce, search, portal, global-search

I already have sidebar="false" showHeader="false"
  but I can still see search on customer portal page. how can I hide this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see its Visualforce ,

You can use StandardStylesheet=false as well to make sure you dont use any salesforce style .

With showheader=false it should ripp off the header completely .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript for this.

Just add below code to your's. It'll remove global search box.

```
<script>
            window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('headerSearchContainer')[0].style.display='none';
            };
</script>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you then please give kudos by clicking on upward arrow of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added my own css file to the visual force page. I created a css uploaded to a static resource and told my vf page to add my css

In the css I put the following to get rid of it. the post removed the hashtag before each ph object you will need to put that in your css when you add these tags

```
phSearchForm {
     display: none !important;
}

phSearchButton {
     display: none !important;
  }


phSearchInput_autoCompleteBoxId .autoCompleteHoverRow {
     display: none !important;
  }

phSearchInput_autoCompleteBoxId .footerRow {
     display: none !important;
  }

phSearchInput {
     display: none !important;
  }
```

On the visual force page I added the standardstylesheets tag and the sidebar tag to my other options and then used the apex:stylesheet to call my static resource css page

```
apex:page standardstylesheets="false" sidebar="false"

apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.CustViewCSS}"/
```